# Can I ssh to other server in Mathematica?

Tags: ssh, wolfram-mathematica

I am a computational chemistry student. I am writing a script which connects to a Linux server and accesses the output files in energy optimizations while they are running. The script extracts all energies and plots them as a function of time.

By doing this, I can see how the optimization is proceeding. The program is not hard but the main problem is how to connect to a remote server. I use a Windows laptop. Now I'm playing a trick. I use the remote kernel function in Mathematica so I can access files and use linux commands on the servers which have Mathematica installed. Unfortunately, not all servers in my lab has Mathematica and I would also like a general solution. When I write

```
Run["ssh servername"]
```

The program hangs. I cannot even abort it. It may be waiting for the password. However, the situation remains same after I set the rsa key without passphrase. Does anyone know how to do it? I have a linux server with Mathematica. I guess it may be easier to use it as a bridge.

Ideally I want the program to popup a window when optimization is done. Does Mathematica support this functionality?

Update: This works, for Q-Chem outputs, when using authentication key without passphrase:

```
Import["!ssh server grep '\"Energy is\"' filename|awk '{print $3}'","Table"]]
```

Comment: `ssh servername` requires an interactive terminal, which you cannot expect Mathematica to give you.  How about doing `ssh servername command`, which will actually run the command you want, then return.  That doesn't require an interactive terminal.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and modification to my question. It works. I have updated my post.